# Multiple selection in same List flutter onTap

Tags: flutter

I define a `bool`, `selected`, to check if any `index` is selected, and an `int`, `selectedIndex`, to save the value of the index selected:

```
bool selected = false;
int selectedIndex = 1;
```

Then, in the build method, I use the variables as below:

```
  return Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 117,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (selectedIndex == index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = 1;
            selected = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
            selected = true;
          });
        }
      },
      child: new Card(
        color:
            (selected && selectedIndex == index) ? Colors.purple : Colors.white,
        elevation: 10,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            ReservationTime.hours[index],
            style: (selected && selectedIndex == index)
                ? TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)
                : TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black87),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

This way I am able to select one item and give to them another color.
What I want to add is multiple selection because at the moment I can select just one item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `List<int>` instead of a single `int`:

```
List<int> selectedIndexes = [1];
// instead of: int selectedIndex = 1;
```

And a function to add/remove selected indexes:

```
void toggleIndex(int i) {
 if (selectedIndexes.contains(i))
   setState(() => selectedIndexes.remove(i));
 else
   setState(() => selectedIndexes.add(i));
 if (selectedIndexes.length > 0)
   setState(() => selected = true);
 else
   setState(() => selected = false);
}
```

Your `Container` will then be:

```
  Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 117,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => toggleIndex(index),
      child: new Card(
        color:
            (selected && selectedIndexes.contains(index)) ? Colors.purple : Colors.white,
        elevation: 10,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            ReservationTime.hours[index],
            style: (selected && selectedIndexes.contains(index))
                ? TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)
                : TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black87),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

You can also get rid of the `selected` variable:

```
List<int> selectedIndexes = [1];

void toggleIndex(int i) {
 if (selectedIndexes.contains(i))
   setState(() => selectedIndexes.remove(i));
 else
   setState(() => selectedIndexes.add(i));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return
  Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 117,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => toggleIndex(index),
      child: new Card(
        color:
            selectedIndexes.contains(index) ? Colors.purple : Colors.white,
        elevation: 10,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            ReservationTime.hours[index],
            style: selectedIndexes.contains(index)
                ? TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)
                : TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black87),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: in the last option to get rid of selected variable I need to change the ```List<int> selectedIndexes = [1];``` to List<int> selectedIndexes = [-1]``` otherwise when I reload the app the first elemen was alwais selected. with -1 I am able to have what I want thanks!